# The code isn't running successfully nor showing any errors

Tags: c

Replacing {{name}} by name string.

**Question:** After exchanging `{{name}}` for `tushar` I am expecting the output `thanks tushar for purchasing {{item}} from our outlet {{outlet}}` but when I run the program it prints empty lines or nothing. What is wrong?

I use vs code and mingw compiler

i cannot figure out why is this happening, and i just wanted to work on my own logic instead of seeing the solution, guide me if the logic i'm using is completely wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>


void func(char *string, char *name, char *outlet, char *item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == '{')
        {
            if (string[i + 2] == 'n')
            {
                int n = i;
                for (int k = 0; k < strlen(name) - 8; k++)
                {
                    for (int l = strlen(string); l >= 15; l--)
                    {
                        string[l + 1] = string[l];
                    }
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < strlen(name); j++)
                {
                    string[n] = name[j];
                    n++;
                }
                i = i + strlen(name);
                continue;
            }

            if (string[i + 2] == 'i')
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (string[i + 2] == 'o')
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr = NULL;
    char string[80] = "thanks {{name}} for purchasing {{item}} from our outlet {{outlet}}";
    char name[50] = "tushar";
    char item[80] = "laptop";
    char outlet[50] = "meerut";
    /*ptr = fopen("file.txt","r+");
    fscanf(ptr,"%[^\n]s",string);
    printf("the content of this file has %s\n",string);*/
    func(string, name, outlet, item);
    printf("%s\n", string);
    // fputs(str,ptr);
    // fclose(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Just showing some blank spaces]

Comment: i think you are better off creating a new string based on your template string since the length of the string may change since all your tokens are longer than 6 characters which is the length of the string you want to insert. just copy the string char by char until you find a { then replace and resuming copying when you find }

Comment: The code had several instances of *undefined behaviour* with its indexing of `string[i + 2]` etc. which can go beyond the bounds of `string`.

Comment: Avoid including `conio.h` (your code doesn't need it). When you include the ancient DOS header `conio.h`, you make your code 100% non-portable to anything other than DOS/windows (of course here, it can simply be deleted)

Comment: @AndersK yeah, let me try that. thanks buddy!

Comment: @WeatherVane but it will trigger only when `string[i] == '{'` , could you please elaborate a bit more or correct my code, it would mean a lot.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin okay I'll definitely do that, could you please tell me the replacements for `getch` and `getchar`. Thanks.

Comment: It might not be the cause with this *specific* input, but writing code on the assumption that the input will always conform to your expectations will never lead to 'robust' code, especially if the data arrives from an external source.

Comment: I suggest you revise the approach and use `sprintf` with the format string `"thanks %s for purchasing %s from our outlet %s";`. It is hard to follow the intent of the code as written. Let the library function do the work.

Comment: i didn't know nothing about `sprintf` , thanks buddy.@WeatherVane

Comment: @TusharKamboj just use `getchar()` from `stdio.h` to hold the terminal open. If you need the keyboard in non-canonical, then if on DOS/Widows -- then that is one use for `getch()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in the code, and I will suggest code that fixes these, and lets the program yield the output you expect.  That said, I will suggest a few changes to make your code more readable and reliable.

**Getting it to work**

The purpose of these loops

```
for (int k = 0; k < strlen(name) - 8; k++)
{
    for (int l = strlen(string); l >= 15; l--)
    {
        string[l + 1] = string[l];
    }
}
```

is to shorten or lengthen the input string to accommodate for the name being shorter or longer than your keyword `{{name}}`.  However, it handles only ONE case, lengthening.  Your name `tushar` is shorter than the keyword, so the final string needs to be *shortened.*

Use this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < 8 - strlen(name); k++)  // number chars to delete from 'string'
{
    for (int l = 14; l <= strlen(string); l++)  // also copy null-terminator
    {
        string[l-1] = string[l];
    }
}
```

**Some suggestions**

Use the debugger in VS Code to help you track variables as they change value, so you can see if your string and array accesses go "out-of-bounds". There are also online debuggers you can use, for example [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), which is what I used to verify the loop changes I added.
Your code is quite [brittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_brittleness) meaning it will work for only very specific and well-behaved input data, and the code is difficult to change. For example, you're not actually testing for `{{name}}`, but only the first `{` and `n`.  So if you want your input string to contain both `{{name}}` and `{{number}}` (and similar) you're in trouble.  Also, there are a few places you traverse or check the string in such a way that you could end up beyond the *end of the string.*  This is not generally allowed in C.  Many of these problems and risks can be avoided by using library functions instead.

Make use of standard *C libraries*, with functions that already do parts of what you want to achieve, for example `sprintf()` to print a string into a buffer, or `strchr()` to find a character in a string, or `strstr()` to find a string in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Mail-merge is *hard* to get right. You are defining your own [regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). The standard library has very basic tools for this job, but fortunately, there are a [lot of tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators#Regular_languages) that are specifically designed for this purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

struct mail_merge { const char *name, *item, *outlet; };

static int mail_merge(FILE *fp, const char *text,
    const struct mail_merge *const mail) {
    const char *YYCURSOR = text, *YYMARKER, *sub0, *sub1;
    /*!stags:re2c format = 'const char *@@;\n'; */
loop:
    /*!re2c
    re2c:yyfill:enable = 0;
    re2c:define:YYCTYPE = char;
    // Used a brace in the text? Can't do that, (this is the simplest.)
    * { return errno = EILSEQ, 0; }
    // Everything except braces and nul gets echoed to the file.
    @sub0 [^{}\x00]+ @sub1
        { fwrite(sub0, 1, (size_t)(sub1 - sub0), fp); goto loop; }
    // These are the special symbols.
    "{{name}}" { fprintf(fp, "%s", mail->name); goto loop; }
    "{{item}}" { fprintf(fp, "%s", mail->item); goto loop; }
    "{{outlet}}" { fprintf(fp, "%s", mail->outlet); goto loop; }
    // A nul-terminator means we are done.
    "\x00" { return 1; }
    */
}

int main(void) {
    const struct mail_merge tushar = { "tushar", "laptop", "meerut" };
    return mail_merge(stdout,
        "thanks {{name}} for purchasing {{item}} from our outlet {{outlet}}\n"
        "thanks again {{name}}\n", &tushar) ? 0 : (perror("mail-merge"), 1);
}
```

For example, running this though [re2c](https://re2c.org/) and then running the generated `.c` through your compiler produces the output expected. Using a [lexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) is generally much simpler, more robust, faster to develop, and faster to run.